# Watin: Determine if Link has disabled="disabled" attribute

Tags: watin

A link coded as:

```
<a id="ButtonNext" disabled="disabled" title="next page">>></a>
```

can be found via:

```
var hasNext = browser.Links.Where(d => d.Id == "ButtonNext">;
```

I need to add a way to detect the `disabled="disabled"` attribute so my branch knows if the .Click() method should be invoked.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WatiN automatically resolve the `disabled` attribute to determine if the control is enable or not.

So you can use the `Enabled` property :

```
var disabledLink = browser.Link(
    l => l.Id == "ButtonNext"
        && !l.Enabled);
```

Note that if you want to get any attribute value of a control, you can use the `GetAttributeValue(string attributeName)` method.

For the `disabled` attribute, WatiN convert the value to a boolean. This code is equivalent to the previous one :

```
var disabledLinkTrue = browser.Link(
    l => l.Id == "ButtonNext"
        && l.GetAttributeValue("disabled") == Boolean.TrueString);
```

Comment: Thanks - very curious about the fact that you are checking for Null before checking the value. It's not a pattern I've seen with Lamdas in general - something specific to Watin?

Comment: Yes and no, WatiN returns control even if they don't have an `Id` or `Name` set, so they can be null, same for `the GetAttributeValue()`. The main point is I used `.Equals()` for case-insensitivity, so I wanted to avoid any NullReferenceException ;) But in fact, it was a bit stupid because DOM attributes are case-sensitive and I think WatiN handles them this way. I simplified the code.